# GSON default date serializer is locale-specific

Tags: java, json, date, gson, utc

In my java application i was using REST API that returned data in JSON format, and noticed that this particular API formatted it's dates in a peculiar way:
"Nov 1, 2019" , But problem is that the actual date on the server is "2019-11-02".That means I am getiing date minimized to previous date.My server is on another country.Below is the complete json that i got after formatting.

```
jsonAccts [{"id":8,"userId":2,"departmentId":45,"effectiveFrom":"Jun 9, 2019","endsOn":"Nov 1, 2019","createdBy":2,"createdOn":"2019-11-02 05:34:11"}]
```

Having this problem on all date fields.What i a solution for this.I need to get the same date on database on REST API request.
Below is the code that i used for gson formatting.

```
    Gson gson;
    GsonBuilder builder;
    SimpleDateFormat dtf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat dtfDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String jsonAccts = null;
    try{
        builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new JsonSerializer<Timestamp>() {
            @Override
            public JsonElement serialize(Timestamp src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                dtf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                String jsDate = dtf.format(src);
                return new JsonPrimitive(jsDate);
            }
        });
        gson = builder.create();
        List<ClassTeacher> allActPgmMap = new ArrayList<ClassTeacher>();
        allActPgmMap = springDao.getClassTeacherList(Integer.parseInt(deptId));
        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ClassTeacher>>() {}.getType();
        jsonAccts = gson.toJson(allActPgmMap, listType);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonAccts;
```

Below is the ClassTeacher class.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.sql.Timestamp;
    import java.util.Date;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "class_teacher")
    public class ClassTeacher implements Serializable,Comparable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private long userId;

        @Column(name = "department_id")
        private long departmentId;

        @Column(name = "effective_from")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)     
        private Date effectiveFrom;

        @Column(name = "ends_on")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)     
        private Date endsOn;

        @Column(name="created_by")
        private long createdBy;

        @Column(name="created_on")
        private Timestamp createdOn;

        public ClassTeacher() {

        }

        public ClassTeacher(long id, long departmentId, long userId, Date effectiveFrom, Date endsOn, long createdBy, Timestamp createdOn) {
            this.id = id;
            this.departmentId = departmentId;
            this.userId = userId;
            this.effectiveFrom = effectiveFrom;
            this.endsOn = endsOn;
            this.createdBy = createdBy;
            this.createdOn = createdOn;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public long getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public long getDepartmentId() {
            return departmentId;
        }

        public void setDepartmentId(long departmentId) {
            this.departmentId = departmentId;
        }

        public Date getEffectiveFrom() {
            return effectiveFrom;
        }

        public void setEffectiveFrom(Date effectiveFrom) {
            this.effectiveFrom = effectiveFrom;
        }

        public Date getEndsOn() {
            return endsOn;
        }

        public void setEndsOn(Date endsOn) {
            this.endsOn = endsOn;
        }

        public long getCreatedBy() {
            return createdBy;
        }

        public void setCreatedBy(long createdBy) {
            this.createdBy = createdBy;
        }

        public Timestamp getCreatedOn() {
            return createdOn;
        }

        public void setCreatedOn(Timestamp createdOn) {
            this.createdOn = createdOn;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            ClassTeacher that = (ClassTeacher) o;

            if (id != that.id) return false;
            if (createdBy != that.createdBy) return false;
            if (userId != null ? !userId.equals(that.userId) : that.userId != null) return false;
            if (departmentId != null ? !departmentId.equals(that.departmentId) : that.departmentId != null) return false;
            if (effectiveFrom != null ? !effectiveFrom.equals(that.effectiveFrom) : that.effectiveFrom != null)
                return false;
            if (endsOn != null ? !endsOn.equals(that.endsOn) : that.endsOn != null) return false;
            if (createdOn != null ? !createdOn.equals(that.createdOn) : that.createdOn != null) return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
            result = 31 * result + (userId != null ? userId.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (departmentId != null ? departmentId.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (effectiveFrom != null ? effectiveFrom.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (endsOn != null ? endsOn.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (int) (createdBy ^ (createdBy >>> 32));
            result = 31 * result + (createdOn != null ? createdOn.hashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object comparestu) {
            return this.getEffectiveFrom().compareTo(((ClassTeacher)comparestu).getEffectiveFrom());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You registered Timestamp type adapter which is using UTC timezone. Did you try setting this timezone to match with the database timezone?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the server is returning the date as "Nov 1, 2019". In this format you don't have the time and the time zone so you won't be able to format the date properly. If you are not able to change the server side i can't see any solution, otherwise there are few solution:

1) When you make the call, send the locale to the server and it will return you the proper date.

2) Change the date format of the server, either return the time in milliseconds or in [ISO 8061](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format - Then when you will parse the date, you can set your locale.

Comment: I was using @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) for date values, thats why date returned in that format, if i remove it then endsOn >= :checkDate conditions will not work if both dates are same.

Comment: Consider the date field is representing date of birth as an example, then there is no need to use the time along with the date.

Comment: Again, you have to take care of the time, at least when you are saving the date. Let's say that the server time is 2 hours before client's time. If you create the date at 00:20 Nov 2 (client time), server time will be 22:20 Nov 1, and then you save just the date (with Temporal annotation). As you can see, the date is Nov 1, and the time is lost, so you have no way of returning the date to Nov 2. One solution is that the client (when creating the date) and the server (when reading the date) use the same locale.

Comment: I have used gson deserialization using UTC time zone while receiving date values from client, so there is no such issues when i save date in server.if client passes nov 1 as date then server saves it as nov 1.

Comment: You are using UTC with Locale.England, and that is UTC+1. But what about client locale? What if the client locale is somewhere in USA, so it is UTC-6 for example. Do you know the clients locale?(or it is default locale, which means that it depends from the location of the client)

Comment: Its Locale.ENGLISH not Locale.England

Comment: Doesn't matter the syntax :D England is UTC+1. That means that if the client sends the Date in UTC and the date is Nov 1 2019 23:10:00, you are formatting the date as +1 hour (Nov 2 2019 00:10:00).

Comment: So what are u telling to do??

Comment: Easiest solution is to tell the client to use Locale.ENGLISH. It will fix the problem.

Comment: Actually i was using Locale.ENGLISH in both sides.My server is locating in Us , so do i need to change the Locale to US in both sides??

Comment: You can try that but, if you have English locale on both sides it should be ok. You should check the reading also. There are 4 places where you have to check if you are using the same locale: 

1. Client side where you send the date to the server
2. Server side, where you read the date
3. Server side where you send the date to the client
4. Client side where you read the date from the server

Answer (score 0):

your problem goes even deeper than this. formatting any kind of date or time object without including the timezone offset is always ambigous. this point in time:

```
1.1.1970 00:00
```

could be interpreted (in UTC) as anything from

```
1.1.1970 14:00 (in kiribati, UTC+14)
```

to

```
31.12.1969 12:00 (in honolulu, UTC -12)
```

to be completety accurate, you would have to EITHER include the timezone offset:

```
1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

the corresponding standard being ISO 8601 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), OR you communicate the reference as part of your interface contract (i.e. in the documentation, say something along the lines of "all dates are in UTC"), which is, frankly, quite cumbersome.

in most situations, i am now using era milliseconds or era seconds for dates in APIs. this makes it a lot clearer what exact point in time you are referring to.

in some situations (e.g. when calculating opening hours for a shop), you will ALSO need to store the timezone information separately, and ideally as a specific reference to a geographic location (in the form of "America/New_York" rather than "EST"), because daylight savings might differ by region, even if these regions do sometimes are on EST (e.g. most places in the USA do have DST, while some places in canada stay on EST all year) - further reading at http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~eggert/tz/tz-link.htm

a java Date object does not know about timezones until you format it, at which point it will (by default) use the system timezone to create a default formatter.

the same goes for parsing dates: after parsing, all timezone information is lost.

**TLDR:**

in short: relying on any kind of timezone agreement is probably not a great idea, you should probably consider including this in all your date fields.

this is all not specifically about your problem though, since what you're asking is how you can set up GSON to use the serializer and desrializer globally. as usual, this depends on who is doing the de/serialization.

this article might help a bit:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-serialization-part-1

however, i find the "era millisecond" approach much easiert: simply declare a field of type "long" as the date, and convert to a date whenever you need it. this also works great for DB queries with < and >